# Is it impossible to sync time on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, time, time-synchronization

I tried every time server out there but all I get is `An error occured while Windows was synchronizing with *time server*`

I also tried the Atomic Clock Sync by WorldTimeServer.com but then the time is offset by 2-3 seconds. I can't believe how hard it is to get an accurate time on my system. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The following KB article covers setting up (and troubleshooting) the ability of Windows to sync with an external NTP time source:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042

In the troubleshooting section, it says:

**Troubleshooting**

For the Windows Time service to function correctly, the networking infrastructure must function correctly. The most common problems that affect the Windows Time service include the following:

- There is a problem with TCP/IP
  connectivity, such as a dead gateway.
- The Name Resolution service is not
  working correctly.
- The network is
  experiencing high volume delays,
  especially when synchronization
  occurs over high-latency wide area
  network (WAN) links.
- The Windows Time
  service is trying to synchronize with
  inaccurate time sources.

Comment: 1. I tracert time.nist.gov and saw no dead gateway
2. Name resolution works
3. Does not explain why I get an error every time
4. I tried every time service

Comment: In the middle of that KB article are some steps that involve changing registry settings.  Take a look at the section titled: Configuring the Windows Time service to use an external time source

Comment: Oh!  I just remembered the solution that worked for me back in the day when I was building new computers...  if the time/date (as set in Windows) is too far off from the real time (I don't know the threshold, maybe a day?), Windows will not update via NTP.  Try setting the time to something close to the real time and try again.  If that didn't work, just waiting a day or so usually resolved whatever random intermittent problem I was hitting.

Comment: If it's only 2-3 seconds off, though, I think that's permissible ntp drift, and it would resync properly after not long.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i am still at a loss though

Answer (score 0):

I guest you sit behind a firewall. NTP uses User Datagram Protocol (UDP) port 123.

Comment: No, no firewall.